# Is there any special rule to use foreach and while loop(using each() function) to iterate over an array in php?

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop

I am new in PHP.
My question is that when i use following script:

```
$arr1 = array('fname' => 'niraj','lname' => 'kaushal','city' => 'lucknow');

while(list($key, $value) = each($arr1)){

echo "$key has $value value <br>";

}

foreach($arr1 as $key => $value){

echo "$key:$value <br>";

}
```

it outputs

```
fname has niraj value 
lname has kaushal value 
city has lucknow value 
fname:niraj 
lname:kaushal 
city:lucknow
```

but when i change order of foreach and while loop as follow

```
$arr1 = array('fname' => 'niraj','lname' => 'kaushal','city' => 'lucknow');

foreach($arr1 as $key => $value){

echo "$key:$value <br>";

}

while(list($key, $value) = each($arr1)){

echo "$key has $value value <br>";

}
```

it gives following output

```
fname:niraj 
lname:kaushal 
city:lucknow
```

Why second script doesn't display the output of while loop. What the reason behind it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because `each()` only returns the current key/value and then advances the internal counter (where in the array you are currently). It does not reset it.

The first loop (`foreach`) sets the internal counter to the end of the array, so the second loop thinks it is already done and therefore does nothing.

You need to call `reset()` on the array before starting the loop using `each()`:

```
reset($arr1);
while (list($key, $value) = each($arr1)){
    echo "$key has $value value <br>";
}
```